# how to download file from google drive using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I am working with download files from google drive. But I am facing lots of issues using google SDK. In developer.google.com there is some examples are available.

```
 GTLServiceDrive *drive = ...;

    GTLDriveFile *file = ...;

    GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [drive.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:file.downloadUrl];`

    `[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
      if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Retrieved file content");
        // Do something with data
      } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);    
      }
    }];
```

I have downloaded new sdks from `developer.google.com` site, but in above example given `GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [drive.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:file.downloadUrl];`. But in new SDK,in this `GTLDriveFile` there is no `downloadURL` object.

And in another example it is asking for client secret key, but when I am selecting type of iOS then there is no option for client secret key. But when I am choosing web that time it is showing. but it is not working.

Please help me how to download file from google drive in iOS using objective c.

Comment: According to the documentation, there is a `downloadURL` object. Please double check if you are using the right resource. See [`downloadURL`](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/reference/ios-client/interface_g_t_l_drive_file.html#a957260925b906876ccaf3598d24fc1dc)

Comment: Hi gerardnimo, I have downloaded new SDK from doveloper.google.com site. I have checked double time, that there is not available downloadURL object in GTLDriveFile. In the documentation there is available, but I think its old documentation. please help me resolve this issue. I am trying last 5 days. still not got any solution.

Answer (score 1):

This may Help you you need to add key (API keys for iOS) param in URL

```
GTLDriveFile *myfile;//Your File Object
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@?key=YOUR_KEY_iOS",
                     myfile.identifier];
    GTMSessionFetcher *fetcher = [self.service.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:url]; //GTLServiceDrive *service;

    [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Retrieved file content");
            // File Downloaded!
        } else {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
        }
    }];
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is needed to add the key (do you mean the authorization token ?) in the url. In the API documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files), it is not mentioned.

Comment: hi, meghs in my case this fetcher service is not working anymore. can you help me for how to download big files with GoogleSDK

Answer (score 0):

From google documentation:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

```
+ (void)downloadFileContentWithService:(GTLServiceDrive *)service
                                  file:(GTLDriveFile *)file
                       completionBlock:(void (^)(NSData *, NSError *))completionBlock {
  if (file.downloadUrl != nil) {
    // More information about GTMHTTPFetcher can be found on
    // <a href="http://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher">http://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher</a>
    GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher =
      [service.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:file.downloadUrl];

    [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
      if (error == nil) {
        // Success.
        completionBlock(data, nil);
      } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
        completionBlock(nil, error);
      }
    }];
  } else {
    completionBlock(nil,
                    [NSError errorWithDomain:NSURLErrorDomain
                                        code:NSURLErrorBadUrl
                                    userInfo:nil]);
  }
}
```

It may be old documentation, so check out this answer:

[Value of type 'GTLDriveFile' has no member 'downloadUrl'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438013/value-of-type-gtldrivefile-has-no-member-downloadurl/35637888#35637888)

Comment: hi david, This is old documentation. In New SDK documentURL object is not available in GTLDriveFile. That's why I am not able to find solution. Please help me if you could found.